# Automatically group new rows by time period as these are being added / recorded

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I've got this Google Sheets file where I'm using one of the sheets as a log / history for registering some values.

My time trigger which will call the function which records data to the log is set by the user. Regardless if the user chooses 1 minute interval or maybe 5, 10, 15 minutes and so on, soon the log sheet will be overpopulated. So I'd like a way for the record script I've got on the Script Editor to automatically group rows as these are being added/recorded on the log sheet automatically by the time trigger, by day and also by month simultaneously. This means Month groups and within these day subgroups and within each of these the 1 minute, or 5 etc, rows were recorded. This would improve navigation of the log sheet immensely. Is this possible?

I've got this record code on the script editor:

```
function RECORD_HISTORY() {
  var historySheetName = "HISTORY";
  var historySheet = getSheetWithName(historySheetName);
  if (historySheet == null) {
    historySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet(historySheetName, 1);
  }

  range = historySheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 9);
  var values = range.getValues();
  values[0][0] = new Date();
  historySheet.appendRow(values[0]);
}

function getSheetWithName(name) {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var idx in sheets) {
    if (sheets[idx].getName() == name) {
      return sheets[idx];
    }
 }
  return null;
}
```

I know there's at least one function that has the power to edit groups etc:

```
shiftRowGroupDepth()
```

All the examples of this function were used in different situations so I couldn't figure out how to go about using this function for my needs. You guys have any idea how to go about to doing this?

Here's a dummy file for you to have a better idea of my log sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc/

**EDIT**:
I want this sheet / script to do everything automatically so neither I or the user need to open the sheet and group rows manually. I don't even want to open the file in order to press a button that calls a function that groups rows. What I want is a way or script that automatically creates groups of rows by month with its own row with the name of the month: AUGUST etc. and then within/below that row/group the days, and within these day groups, the rest of the rows with the hourly logs. This row grouping function should happen automatically, while the file is closed, and the data is being recorded to the log by the function that records data which is called through a time trigger.

I want the user to have no role whatsoever in handling information, grouping etc. The user should just open the spreadsheet in order to be able to get an easy fast interpretation of the data, and be able to navigate it easily.

Also I would like the rows to be automatically collapsed after they are created and not remain expanded because if would confuse the user.

Finally would this be easier to do if the code was combined with the recording function I wrote? "RECORD_HISTORY()"

Let me know if this was clear enough. Regarding the time zone, mine is GMT+01:00.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not a design question, its a code question. How to use code to automatically group rows by month and day as they are being recorded. How is this design?

Comment: Can you provide your expected output?

Comment: If there is not blank row between `0:00` and `0:01`, you cannot separate their groups (will be concatenated). Please show how you are going to solve it.

Comment: What do you mean Jason?

Comment: Can't access your dummy file. Also, what I mean is can you provide your expected output based on your dummy file?

Comment: Ok I will make a series of groups on the left so you have an idea.

Comment: OK you can check the file now. Thanks!

Comment: If you group rows `2:3`, and then group rows `4:5`, they will be concatenated and rows `2:5` will be in the same group. But it seems you would only group row `3` and leave row `2` there; and group row `5` and leave row `4` there.

Comment: What you asked was 'Month groups and within these day subgroups'. The solution is provided in my answer. SO is not writing code for you. Please try yourself and ask for further help (please create a new question) if you need.

Comment: Some tips: you may create an `onOpen` trigger to collapse the groups, call `groupRow` at the end of `RECORD_HISTORY`, `timezone` maybe `BST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```js
function groupRow() {
  const timeZone = 'Your time zone';
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const rowStart = 6;
  const rows = sheet.getLastRow() - rowStart + 1;
  const values = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat();
  
  const o = {};
  values.forEach((date, i) => {
    const [m, d] = Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, 'yyyyMM,dd').split(',');
    if (!o[m]) { o[m] = {}; }
    if (!o[m][d]) { o[m][d] = []; }
    o[m][d].push(rowStart + i);
  });
  // console.log(o);
  for (const m in o) { o[m] = Object.values(o[m]); }
  // console.log(o);
  
  Object.values(o).forEach(m => {
    for (const d of m) {
      if (d.length === 1) { continue; }
      const range = `${d[1]}:${d.slice(-1)[0]}`;
      // console.log('d', range);
      sheet.getRange(range).shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
    }
    const a = m.flat();
    if (a.length === 1) { return; }
    const range = `${a[1]}:${a.slice(-1)[0]}`;
    // console.log('m', range);
    sheet.getRange(range).shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
  });
}
```

Comment: The script automatically groups rows but the last hour is grouped on the day before. Can it be fixed?
Does the script automatically group rows as data is being added every hour? That would ideal. Or would I have to come every now and then to call the function? If so would it regroup the previously grouped rows or just the new non grouped rows at the bottom?
Finally: Is it possible for this script to also group by month? Like on the 31 st of a month or 30th etc, at 00:00 it groups all rows before into a month and creates a new row with the month name?
Thanks!

Comment: I think the first issue is due to the improper time zone you set. Please double check. Regarding the other issues, please add to your question and elaborate them one by one.

Comment: Ok I just did that. Hope it's clear enough.