# Automatically group new rows as these are being added to the log by day, month and year

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I asked for help in another question and a user gave me this script which partially does what I need: it automatically creates groups of rows by day and month when the function is executed. I would like this script to do several more things than just grouping the rows when I press a button or call the function some other way.

1. I would like this grouping function to be done automatically so that
   I don't have to open the file and press a button or run the
   function manually. For this I was advised to call the function at the end of
   another function I got that records new rows at the bottom of the
   sheet with the new data. This recording function I got is executed
   through a  timer script ATM set at 1 hour. Problem is whenever this
   function that creates the groups is executed, it will group
   everything again, creating duplicates of groups, thus enlarging the
   group bar at the left which doesn't look pretty. It's good that the
   function creates all this groups when it is executed for the first
   time. But if it is executed again it does everything all over again.
   It would be better if the function, when it is executed for the 2nd,
   3rd time etc could just detect which rows are left ungrouped and
   then would either add these new rows to a previously created group
   if these new rows would belong to the previous day group, or just
   create a new group for the next day group and add these new groups
   to this new one and so on, without duplicating groups.
2. Presently this script / function does not create a group
   for the year. I would like it to also create a group for the whole year which would
   contain month groups and within these, day groups. Is it possible?
3. Also it would be great if these group function could create a blank
   row just with the name of the month at the beginning of the month
   group, and this row would be the first group row, thus it would be
   the one visible when rows are collapsed. Also the same for when a
   year ends and a new year starts: a new blank row just with the year:
   2022, 2023 etc.
4. Also I would like the function to collapse the groups right after it
   is executed for the first time and to also collapse a group that is presently opened
   like a group created for the present day, and then right when the
   day is over at 24h, the function collapses it, creates a new group
   for the next day keeping this last one opened.

Of course if would be better if someone could just write the code for me. ATM I'm learning how to code and my knowledge is limited. I would like at least to understand the code and what each line does so I can understand it better and maybe I one day can rewrite this code so it can do what I need.

So here is the function that creates the groups:

```
function groupRow() {

    const timeZone = "GMT+1";
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    const rowStart = 5;
    const rows = sheet.getLastRow() - rowStart + 1;
    const values = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat();
    const o = [];

    values.forEach((date, i) => {
        const [m, d] = Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, "yyyyMM,dd").split(",");
        if (!o[m]) {
            o[m] = [];
        }
        if (!o[m][d]) {
            o[m][d] = [];
        }
        o[m][d].push(rowStart + i);
    });

    var collator = new Intl.Collator([], {numeric: true});

    for (var m in o) {
     o[m] = Object.values(o[m]).sort((a,b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b));
    }

    Object.values(o).forEach(m => {
        for (const d of m) {
            if (d.length === 1) {
            continue;
            }
            const range = `${ d[1] }:${ d.slice(-1)[0] }`;
            sheet.getRange(range).shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
        }
        const a = m.flat();
        if (a.length === 1) {
            return;
        }
        const range = `${ a[1] }:${ a.slice(-1)[0] }`;
        sheet.getRange(range).shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
    });
}
```

Here's my dummy file with an example of what is happening on my main file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ExXtmQ8nyuV1o_UtabVJ-TifIbORItFMWjtN6ZlruWc

EDIT:
I replied to my question with the final solution.

Comment: "_it would be better if someone could just write the code for me_" - Someone may do that for you, but that is not really how this site works, for reasons covered [elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165712/stack-overflow-faq-should-specifically-reference-please-write-me-this-code).

Comment: You have provided some code (that is a great start, thank you) - but maybe you can clarify where you are _specifically_ getting stuck. What _specific_ section of code does not work? What happens when it runs? Are there any errors? What needs to happen instead? What data & code can we use to recreate the _specific_ problem for ourselves? See also [mre]

Comment: Thank you. I look at this code and it's very difficult to understand. I can understand the type of code used for the recording script for new rows on the file I provided. Not this one. So basically right now I'm stuck with the part of not duplicating groups. That would be a good start and would make me satisfied for now. I just don't understand what needs to be done here so it does not duplicate groups.

Comment: I think those questions you ask on your 2nd comment Is on the text no? When it runs it groups by month and day all the ungrouped rows. No errors. It needs for now not to duplicate groups. Open the file and run the function twice and you can see what happens. Thank you

Comment: SO is asking for minimal example. You should not ask contributor to try themselves nor read some long text.

Comment: What you have provided us in the text of your question is more like a set of requirements than a SO question. Someone may be able to fulfill those requirements for you. But you may also find your question gets closed or down-voted - and I would like to help you avoid both of those outcomes.

Comment: I have gave you the hints about how to achieve what you want in [the previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775566/automatically-group-new-rows-by-time-period-as-these-are-being-added-recorded). Have you tried? If no please first try yourself, then update and feedback us.

Comment: Ok sorry guys. Did not try the onOpen trigger for rows collapsing yet. Timezone works ok with "GMT+1". I added this groupRow function at the end of my recording script. So it runs every time recording script is called every 1 hour. Problem is this duplicates groups. This is the main problem. If I add a condition like: if rows are already grouped group only new rows, else group everything would it avoid duplicating groups?

Comment: Close but not exact. That code was a full run. It group all rows at the first execution as you observe. What you need to do upon each `RECORD_HISTORY` is only to compare with the second last row to 1) see if it has to group to the day; 2) group all rows of the last month if month has changed

Comment: Oh my brain hurts I have no idea how to do this. What do I need to do to get good at this level of coding? Do I need to learn Javascript from scratch? Because Google App Script is based on Javascript. Or is there a language better for learning to code? Python?

Comment: Start small. Go step-by-step, line-by-line. Do the intro tutorials (try a few different ones). Learn how to debug (e.g. by using print statements). Then come back to this more challenging piece of code. Your learning will be cumulative - and it will start to make a _lot_ more sense, after that. Ask questions here. But try to avoid (a) questions which have already been asked and answered; (b) questions to which the answer will be "go do a tutorial first". The specific language does not matter so much (at first). JavaScript and Python are both great choices. And all our brains often hurt.

Comment: Ok thanks man I am trying to learn line by line yes. Thanks! =)

Comment: values.forEach((date, i)    
In this line what does the " i " do? Can't find anything on this because so much results show up for "i" meaning other stuff.

Comment: Edited a change in the code to make it better because there was an error at the 10th day of each month it would not group months and would group 2 last rows of the 9th and 2 first of 10th.

Comment: Look at the official [`forEach()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Notice how the function has several forms it can take. One of those forms is `forEach((element, index) => { ... } )` - that looks like it fits what you have! It takes 2 parameters, the same as yours does. The documentation explains the rest. Also, go look at `forEach()` tutorials.

Comment: Also, you can `console.log()` the values of your `date` and your `i` variables inside the body of the `forEach()` loop, to see the data for yourself... So, there is a lot you can do to help yourself. You can use `console.log()` in many situations to explore what is going on.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. I have been actually reading that website and try to understand line by line how this works. It's hard. Specially when it comes to connecting all the pieces together in my head and have a clear understanding. But I am getting there. Will keep this updated.

Comment: Andrew your code for the group rows really helped me out figuring this out. Final solution is below. Thanks!

Comment: Actually there were problems so I had to change everything. Edited the solution. Thanks again @andrewjames

Comment: Thank you @idfurw below is final solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to make this group automatically group rows. With help from folks from Stackoverflow of course. This is what I've got:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CONSTANT VARIABLE DECLARATION
// Identify Sheet, TimeZone and Locale

const logSheetNameYR = "LOG";
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetNameYR);
const timeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
const locale = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetLocale();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// GROUPROWS
// Used for defining where to start grouping inconjunction with 'rowStart'

let rowBlock = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValue();   // Get value for second last row
let cells;
let firstRowOfBlock;

// Used for getting the arrays with blocks of rows of `d`+ `m`+ `y`
let range = sheet.getRange("A5:A");
let startRow = range.getRow();
let [y, m, d] = Utilities.formatDate(rowBlock, timeZone, "yyyy,MM,dd").split(",");

// GROUP ROWS BY YEARS
function group_by_years() {
    // Used to get block of rows for last year
    let cells = range.getValues().map((x, i) => x.concat(i + startRow)).filter(x => {   // filter "dd"
        let date = new Date(x[0]);
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        return (`${y}` === `${year}`)
    }).map(x => x[1]);
    firstRowOfBlock = cells[0];   // Used to get index of block of rows
    // Creates new row with year number for easy group navigation
    sheet.insertRowBefore(cells[0]);
    sheet.getRange(cells[0], 1).setValue(new Date(y, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)).setNumberFormat('YYYY');
    sheet.getRange(firstRowOfBlock, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).setBackground('#131928');
    sheet.getRange(cells[0], 1).setFontSize(10);
    sheet.getRange(cells[0], 1).setFontWeight("bold");
    // Debuging console logs
    //console.log("groupRows() -> group_by_years() ->",timeZone);
    //console.log("groupRows() -> group_by_years() ->","cells:", cells);
    //console.log("groupRows() -> group_by_years() ->","cells[0]:", cells[0]);
    // Grouping Function.
    get_rows_array().forEach(y => shift_rows(y.map(m => m.flat()).flat(), sheet));
}

// GROUP ROWS BY MONTHS
function group_by_months() {
    // Used to get block of rows for last month
    let cells = range.getValues().map((x, i) => x.concat(i + startRow)).filter(x => {   // filter "dd"
        let date = new Date(x[0]);
        let month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        return (`${m}` === `${month}` && `${y}` === `${year}`)
    }).map(x => x[1]);
    firstRowOfBlock = cells[0];   // Used to get index of block of rows
    // Creates new row with month name for easy group navigation
    sheet.insertRowBefore(cells[0]);
    sheet.getRange(cells[0], 1).setValue(new Date(y, m - 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)).setNumberFormat('MMMM');
    sheet.getRange(firstRowOfBlock, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).setBackground('#131928');
    sheet.getRange(cells[0], 1).setFontSize(9);
    sheet.getRange(cells[0], 1).setFontWeight("bold");
    // Debuging console logs
    //console.log("groupRows() -> group_by_months() ->","cells:", cells);
    //console.log("groupRows() -> group_by_months() ->","cells[0]:", cells[0]);
    // Grouping function.
    get_rows_array().flat().forEach(m => shift_rows(m.flat(), sheet));
}

// GROUP ROWS BY DAYS
function group_by_days() {
    // Used to get block of rows for last day "dd", month "MM" and year "YYYY"
    let cells = range.getValues().map((x, i) => x.concat(i + startRow)).filter(x => {   // filter "dd"
        let date = new Date(x[0]);
        let day = date.getDate();
        let month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        let year = date.getFullYear();
        return (`${d}` === `${day}` && `${m}` === `${month}` && `${y}` === `${year}`)
    }).map(x => x[1]);
    firstRowOfBlock = cells[0];   // Used to get index of block of rows
    // Debuging console logs
    //console.log("groupRows() -> group_by_days() ->","cells:", cells);
    //console.log("groupRows() -> group_by_days() ->", "cells[0]:", cells[0]);
    // Grouping Function
    get_rows_array().flat().flat().forEach(d => shift_rows(d.flat(), sheet));
}

function get_rows_array() {
    let rowStart = firstRowOfBlock;
    let rows = sheet.getLastRow() - rowStart + 1;
    let values = sheet.getRange(rowStart, 1, rows, 1).getValues().flat();
    let o = {};
    // make the object {'year': { 'month':[days] } }
    values.forEach((date, i) => {
        let [y, m, d] = Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, "yyyy,MM,dd").split(",");
        // console.log(y, m, d);
        if (!o[y]) o[y] = {};
        if (!o[y][m]) o[y][m] = {};
        if (!o[y][m][d]) o[y][m][d] = [];
        o[y][m][d].push(rowStart + i);
    });

    // convert the unordered object {year:{month:[days]}}
    // into the ordered 3d-array [year[month[days]]]
    const numsort = (a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b);
    return Object.keys(o).sort(numsort)
        .map(y => Object.keys(o[y]).sort(numsort)
            .map(m => Object.values(o[y][m]).sort(numsort)));
}

function shift_rows(rows, sheet) {
    if (rows.length === 1) return;
    let range = `${rows[1]}:${rows.slice(-1)}`;
    sheet.getRange(range).shiftRowGroupDepth(1);
    // Collapse group.
    let groupClps = sheet.getRowGroup(firstRowOfBlock, 1);
    groupClps.collapse();

}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CHECKROWS
// Function that compares 2 last rows to determine: change by day, change by month, change by year

function checkRows() {
    const logSheetNameYR = "LOG";
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(logSheetNameYR);
    const timeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();

    let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    let secondLastRow = lastRow - 1;

    let dateLast = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).getValue();
    let dateSecondLast = sheet.getRange(secondLastRow, 1).getValue();

    console.log("checkRows():", dateSecondLast);
    console.log("checkRows():", dateLast);

    // retrieving day of the month from last 2 rows
    let dayLastRow = Utilities.formatDate(dateLast, timeZone, "dd");
    let daySecondLastRow = Utilities.formatDate(dateSecondLast, timeZone, "dd");

    // retrieving month nº from last 2 rows
    let monthLastRow = Utilities.formatDate(dateLast, timeZone, "MM");
    let monthSecondLastRow = Utilities.formatDate(dateSecondLast, timeZone, "MM");

    // retrieving year from last 2 rows
    let yearLastRow = Utilities.formatDate(dateLast, timeZone, "yyyy");
    let yearSecondLastRow = Utilities.formatDate(dateSecondLast, timeZone, "yyyy");

    console.log("checkRows():", dayLastRow, monthLastRow, yearLastRow);
    console.log("checkRows():", daySecondLastRow, monthSecondLastRow, yearSecondLastRow);

    if (yearLastRow > yearSecondLastRow) {
        group_by_years();
        group_by_months();
        group_by_days();
        console.log("checkRows():", yearSecondLastRow + ' ->', yearLastRow + ' -', "Year went up. So day and month went up too, though they went back to 1. Y + M + d Grouping executed");
    } else {
        console.log("checkRows():", yearSecondLastRow + ' ->', yearLastRow + ' -', "Year didn't go up.");
        if (monthLastRow > monthSecondLastRow) {
            group_by_months();
            group_by_days();
            console.log("checkRows():", monthSecondLastRow + ' ->', monthLastRow + ' -', "Month went up. So day went up too, even though it went back to 1. But year didn't. M + d Grouping executed");
        } else {
            console.log("checkRows():", monthSecondLastRow + ' ->', monthLastRow + ' -', "Month didn't go up.");
            if (dayLastRow > daySecondLastRow) {
                group_by_days();
                console.log("checkRows():", daySecondLastRow + ' ->', dayLastRow + ' -', "Day went up. So month and year didn't. d Grouping executed");
            } else {
                console.log("checkRows():", daySecondLastRow + ' ->', dayLastRow + ' -', "Day didn't go up.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```